# is the compositum of a family of algebraic extensions algebraic?

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $F$ be a field contained inside another field $K$. Let $\Gamma$ be an indexing set (possibly infinite). Let $\lbrace E_i\rbrace_{i\in\Gamma}$ be a collection of algebraic extensions of $F$ contained inside $K$. Is it true that the compositum of the $E_{i}'s$ will be algebraic over $F$ ?

For example, consider $F=\mathbb{Q}$ and $K=\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ and $E_i=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p_i})$, where $p_i$ is the $i$-th prime. Is the compositum of $E_i's$ algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Extension of a field $k$ is algebraic iff it is generated by elements algebraic over $k$.

Since the compositum of $\{E_i\}_{i\in \Gamma}$ inside $F$ is a subfield of $F$ generated by $\bigcup_{i\in \Gamma} E_i$ and all elements of this set are algebraic over $k$, it follows that the compositum of these fields is algebraic over $k$

Answer (score 1):

the field compositum of the $E_{i}'s$ is sub field of the closure
algebriac field of $F$ in $K$ so it is algebraic over $F$, and clearly the compositum of $E_i=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p_i})$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$